# Catch Reset Password Link in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In connection to my question:

[Creating Password Reset Function without using Laravel make:auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764888/creating-password-reset-function-without-using-laravel-makeauth)

The mailer sent the reset email url in my email. But if i click in the link, the object was not found because the URL is not existed in my `routes.php`

My question:

How can i catch the reset password link?

My Controller:

```
   public function recover(Request $request)
{
    $user = Admin::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $error_message = "Your email address was not found.";
        return redirect()->back()->with(['errors' => $error_message]);
    }
    try {
        Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject('Your Password Reset Link');
        });
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        return redirect()->back()->with(['errors' => $error_message]);
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'A reset email has been sent! Please check your email.']);
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::post('/forgot', [
'uses' => 'RegisterController@recover',
'as' => 'password.reset'
]);
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
```

The email link given in reset password:

```
http://localhost/forgot?c2108023762b4f86029d5758207cb4156fd58052ad9d6b13b729ce84092937de
```

Comment: Your route for reset password link and the actual link is entirely different. Please check.

Comment: i tried to change the route from
`Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');`

to

`Route::get('forgot?{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');`

but still not found!

Comment: Remove `?` from `{token?}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch that by **`Request::query()`** function.
See sample code below:

```
// http://localhost/forgot?c2108023762b4f86029d5758207cb4156fd58052ad9d6b13b729ce84092937de

Route::get('forgot', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $query = $request->query();
    $token = (array_keys($query))[0];
    echo $token; // c2108023762b4f86029d5758207cb4156fd58052ad9d6b13b729ce84092937de
});
```